# Dealing with conflicts on linux installs

Tags: yum, repository

I am trying to run a linux install.

I have added a rpm repo.

and i am running

```
yum install normalize
```

But i am getting the following error

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib64/libmp3lame.so.0.0.0 from install of libmp3lame0-3.99.3-23.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libmp3lame-3.98.4-4.el6.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

How do you deal with these types of errors?

I have tried

```
yum remove lame
```

Then re installed still getting the error.

Do i find the file and delete it i think the other lame was installed via ffmeg.

A bit lost and would appreciate some help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using different repos that are not compatible, you should look at yum-priorities plugin. It will ignore packages from lower ranked repos even if they are newer than the installed one.

You can find a manual [here](http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities) .
There is some trickery to do the correct priorities but a good rule is to look to the repo project page. Sometimes you can find a description with what repo they are compatible.

My priorities are:

1. Base and Updates
2. epel
3. rpmfusion
4. others